# How to split a document in pandas dataframe and create rows for each sentence

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have dataframe of 1 row with a long document. I want to split the document by sentence (sent_tokenize) and then create rows for each sentence so that the number of observations increases, say, from 1 (document) to 10,000 (sentences) observations. 
For instance, my document has only one row as shown below:

```
      document                      category
0     life is full of fake data..   wonderland
```

What I want is the document is split by sentence and create rows for all sentences

```
      document                      category
0     life is full of fake data..   wonderland
1     but you have to sort out..    wonderland
2     what is fake what is not..    wonderland
      ..........
10000 you will get what you want.   wonderland
```

Honestly, I have not idea how I should approach it. I tokenized the sentence by `sent_tokenize` but do not how how to `split` by sentence and create rows.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there are more efficient ways of doing this, but this was flexible enough to give the desired output. Basically, iterate over the dataframe, split the text based cell into sentences, and create new rows while carrying over the category for each sentence:

```
test = """This is a sentence. This is another sentence. 
          This is a third sentence. We want a separate row for each sentence."""


df = pd.DataFrame({'docs': test, 'category': 'winterland'}, index=[0])

df_new = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'doc': doc, 'category': row['category']}, index=[0]) 
           for _, row in df.iterrows() 
           for doc in row['docs'].split('.') if doc != ''])
```

df_new should have your desired output. You could use sent_tokenize here or for more advanced sentence boundary detection, you could use [Spacy's](https://spacy.io/) sent method. Spacy has a host of amazing features and is very customizable for NLP projects.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am actually working with some documents. education = pd.DataFrame({'text': kabir, 'policy_time': 'Bangladesh_2010'}, index=[0])

education_policy = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'text_2': text_2, 'policy_time': row['policy_time']}, index=[0]) 
           for _, row in education.iterrows() 
           for text in row['text'].split('.') if text != ''])

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be to split by `('.')`

so using same test as datawrestler:

`test = """This is a sentence. This is another sentence. 
          This is a third sentence. We want a separate row for each sentence."""`

We can split the row into a list that we feed to the dataframe like below:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'docs': test.split('.'), 'category': 'winterland'})`

The only difference in the result is that you will have a blank row at the bottom, which you can filter out if needed, alternatively you can use list comprehension when you create the dataframe to exclude blank rows like below:

`pd.DataFrame({'docs': [sentence for sentence in test.split('.') if sentence !=''], 'category': 'winterland'})`

Answer (score 0):

You could use textblob:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
text1='''That's right....the red velvet cake.....ohhh this stuff is so good.    
They never brought a salad we asked for.    
This hole in the wall has great Mexican street tacos, and friendly staff.'''

blob=TextBlob(text1)
df=blob.sentences
```